# I deleted my light source... now my bakes look pitch black

Tags: uv, light, texture-baking, baking

If i remember correctly, if you deleted your only light source in a scene, blender would automatically light everything related to bakes as seen in the image below
[image: white]

apparently, if you delete your only light source in a scene on blender 2.9, your bakes will be pitch black as seen in the image below

[image: black]

I'm quite new to blender 2.9 and i don't really know how to fix this without adding a new light source, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid because i want the results as seen in the first image

Comment: So basically what's your question?

Comment: what kind of bake is it? I think that if you want to bake the diffuse for example, you can disable the direct and indirect lightings

Comment: moonboots, combined.

Answer (score 0):

This s not related to Version 2.9 or 2.x
When you bake combined you should have a source light , or just uncheck Direct and in direct light or just bake Defuse as [moonboos](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots) mentioned :)